# python select files from a directory whose date modified time is less than a particular date

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of file location. I am looping through each file and want to see if there is any file which has been modified before 3 days then I created a new list with those file. i.e
modified_lst_file.
datetime.timedelta(days=(3)).total_seconds() --> retun right value 259200.0 (3 days in seconds)
The issue is os.path.getmtime(file) returning me a float value like  1626188616.2838614. How do I convert it into seconds ,so that I can do a comparison.
Or is there a better and easier approach to do this ?

```
            modified_lst_file =[]
            for file in lst_file :
                if (os.path.getmtime(file) < datetime.timedelta(days=(3)).total_seconds()):
                    modified_lst_file.append(file)
            return None, modified_lst_file
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a way around this using list comprehension

```
[f for f in lst_file if datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(f)) < (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=(3)))]
```

Comment: I think calculating `datetime.datetime.now()` one time is enough.

Comment: @S.B yes that is correct